# How to take the partial derivative $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}_z$ if $x$ occurs in our definition of $x$ itself?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}_z$ holds $z$ constant. If our definition of $x$ has $x$ occuring on the right hand side, do we assume $x$ is "constant" for the purposes of our partial differentiation? i.e. is $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}_z = \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}_{x,z}$?

Comment: Do you have a particular example in mind? I have a few, but I want to make sure we're on the same page, because this sounds like just using the chain rule.

Comment: lets say, $x = \frac{y}{c + x^2}$?

Comment: In $\quad x=\frac{y}{c+x^2}\quad$ there is no $z$ . So the partial derivative with respect to $z$ is $0$. Probably the wording of the question is ambiguous or incomplete.

Comment: The partial is respect to y. The "z" means it stays constant. Okay, we can use $x = \frac{yz}{c+x^2}$